# How to make Apache load different .htaccess files based on hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there a way for Apache to load a different .htaccess file based upon hostname?

For example, for a web server that has 2 hostnames (**example1.com** and **example2.com**) that share the same web directory, it is possible to make Apache load `/.1-htaccess` when a user visits example1.com, but `/.2-htaccess` for example2.com?

Note: this is intended to avoid using the HTTP_HOST `RewriteCond` rewrites.

Comment: Having 2 .htaccess is not possible but you can have 2 different `VirtualHost` entries with different set of rules.

Comment: Is it possible to define htaccess rules for the shared directory in each `VirtualHost` entry?

Comment: Yes it is definitely possible to have separate rules in `VirtualHost` blocks